# What distinguishes elliptical coordinates from polar coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I am trying to identify what characteristic distinguishes elliptical
coordinates from polar coordinates. For concreteness, let's write down
the expressions.

Polar:

$$
x=r \cos(t) \\
y=r \sin(t)
$$

Elliptical:

$$
x=a \cosh(r) \cos(t) \\
y=a \sinh(r) \sin(t)
$$

(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system)

The most obvious distinction is that the "normal" lines to the ellipses
are not straight lines but curved (in fact confocal parabolas).

Another way to say it is that for polar coordinates the normal vector
$(dx/dr,dy/dr)$ depends on $t$ only, not on $r$, and is thus normal to all
circles (any $r$), whereas for elliptical coordinates the normal vector
depends on both $r$ and $t$, so is normal to the ellipse for a specific $r$ and $t$.

So my questions are:

1. Is this a good characterization of the difference, and is it possible
   to state it in a more insightful manner in a larger context?
2. Is there a different or better way to characterize the difference?
3. Is there a name for it?

Comment: Another way to sum that up: draw one of the normal lines and a sequence of tangent vectors to that line (which are, of course, normal vectors to different ellipses). Then there's a difference between being 'parallel to the line' and 'parallel in the plane' which didn't exist in the polar case.